# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' In a machine learning application in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nonetype

These are my codes that I get an error when I run:

```
def my_tokenizer(text):
    if text is None:
        return []
    else:
        return text.split()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=my_tokenizer)
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])
```

This is my error output:

```
---> 69     doc = doc.lower()
     70 if accent_function is not None:
     71     doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I looked at the sample solutions and got my code from this:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split())
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])
```

I converted it to the above. But I still get the same error and I don't know what to fix:

Comment: What is `CountVectorizer`? What module was that imported from?

Comment: Always provide the _full_ error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default CountVectorizer will try to convert all inputs to lowercase. Since you have None in your input, `lower()` cannot be applied.

To fix this particular problem you can provide `lowercase = False` argument when initializing the CountVectorizer. However, a safer approach would be to remove all occurrences of None from your input before passing to the vectorizer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand what you mean but I don't know how to display this in code. Can you help me?

Comment: You could try something like this `tags = [str(t) for t in tag_data["Tags"]]` to replace None with a string "None".